# Pandas find every row in df1 where df2 matches either column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas dataframes.  I would like to use the values in df2 and find the full row in df1 where it matches.

df1

```
   col1   col2
0  55     66
1  12     25 
2  18     22 
3  52     15
4  15     30
5  16     17
6  17     30
7  31     20
```

df2

```
   duplicates
0  15
1  17
```

I want to use the values in df2 and iterate through df1 and recieve and output like the following:

df3

```
   col1   col2
3  52     15
4  15     30
5  16     17
6  17     30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `isin` with `any`

```
df1[df1.isin(df2.duplicates.values).any(1)]
Out[26]: 
   col1  col2
3    52    15
4    15    30
5    16    17
6    17    30
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to check if any columns in a given row are `True`:

```
df1[df1.isin(df2.duplicates.values).any(1)]

    col1  col2
3    52    15
4    15    30
5    16    17
6    17    30
```